# Finding equilibrium points of a non-linear differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, stability-in-odes

I'm trying to find the equilibrium points of 
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=-1-y-e^{x} \\
\dot{y}=x^2+y(e^x-1) \\
\dot{z}=x+\sin(z) \\
\end{cases}$$

My try:

$$\dot{x}=0\Rightarrow -1-y-e^x=0\Rightarrow y=-1-e^x.$$

Replacing in $\dot{y}$,

$$x^2+(-1-e^x)(e^x-1)=0\Rightarrow x^2+1-e^{2x}=0\Rightarrow x=0\Rightarrow y=-2 $$ 
Replacing in $\dot{z}$,

$$\sin(z)=0\Rightarrow z=n\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}. $$

So, for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(0,-2,n\pi)$ is a equilibrium point. But I don't know if exists another equilibrium points. 
What can I do?

Comment: Please check again carefully what you've written. First you have $1$, then $-1$.What's the right one?

Comment: If  $\dot{x}=0$ then $1-y-e^x=0$ you seem to have an extra negative sign

Comment: @amsmath sorry, fixed

Comment: You forgot negative $n$, so $n\in\Bbb Z$. Otherwise everything is fine.